# Extract and Replace values from duplicates rows in PySpark Data Frame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, rdd

I have duplicate rows of the may contain the same data or having missing values in the PySpark data frame.
The code that I wrote is very slow and does not work as a distributed system.
Does anyone know how to retain single unique values from duplicate rows in a PySpark Dataframe which can run as a distributed system and with fast processing time?

I have written complete Pyspark code and this code works correctly.
But the processing time is really slow and its not possible to use it on a Spark Cluster.

'''

```
# Columns of duplicate Rows of DF

dup_columns = df.columns

for row_value in df_duplicates.rdd.toLocalIterator():
    print(row_value)

# Match duplicates using std name and create RDD

    fill_duplicated_rdd = ((df.where((sf.col("stdname") == row_value['stdname'] ))
                        .where(sf.col("stdaddress")== row_value['stdaddress']))
                   .rdd.map(fill_duplicates))

    # Creating feature names for the same RDD 

    fill_duplicated_rdd_col_names = (((df.where((sf.col("stdname") == row_value['stdname']) &
                                    (sf.col("stdaddress")== row_value['stdaddress'])))
                   .rdd.map(fill_duplicated_columns_extract)).first())

    # Creating DF using the previous RDD
    # This DF stores value of a single set of matching duplicate rows

    df_streamline = fill_duplicated_rdd.toDF(fill_duplicated_rdd_col_names)

    for column in df_streamline.columns:
        try:

            col_value = ([str(value[column]) for value in 
                      df_streamline.select(col(column)).distinct().rdd.toLocalIterator() if value[column] != ""])        

            if len(col_value) >= 1:
                # non null or empty value of a column store here
                # This value is a no duplicate distinct value
                col_value = col_value[0]
                #print(col_value)

                # The non-duplicate distinct value of the column is stored back to 
                # replace any rows in the PySpark DF that were empty.

                df_dedup = (df_dedup
              .withColumn(column,sf.when((sf.col("stdname") == row_value['stdname'])
                                      & (sf.col("stdaddress")== row_value['stdaddress'])
                                         ,col_value)
                          .otherwise(df_dedup[column])))

            #print(col_value)
        except:
            print("None")
```

'''

There are no error messages but the code is running very slow. I want a solution that fills rows with unique values in PySpark DF that are empty. It can fill the rows with even mode of the value

Answer (score 0):

"""

```
df_streamline = fill_duplicated_rdd.toDF(fill_duplicated_rdd_col_names)

    for column in df_streamline.columns:
        try:

           # distinct() was replaced by isNOTNULL().limit(1).take(1) to improve the speed of the code and extract values of the row.

           col_value  = df_streamline.select(column).where(sf.col(column).isNotNull()).limit(1).take(1)[0][column]

            df_dedup = (df_dedup
              .withColumn(column,sf.when((sf.col("stdname") == row_value['stdname'])
                                         & (sf.col("stdaddress")== row_value['stdaddress'])
                                         ,col_value)
                          .otherwise(df_dedup[column])))
```

"""